# Unable to copy custom files in Sitecore identity server

Tags: docker

I am trying to deploy some custom files in my Sitecore identity server. As you can see in the below screenshot,the files are copied into c:\deploy folder within container but not getting copied from c:\deploy to c:\identity within container.

My docker-compose.override id section is :

```
id:
   image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-id:${VERSION:-latest}
   build:
     context: ./docker/build/id
     args:
       BASE_IMAGE: scr.sitecore.com/sxp/sitecore-id7:10.3-ltsc2019
       TOOLING_IMAGE: scr.sitecore.com/tools/sitecore-docker-tools-assets:10.2-1809
   volumes:
    - ${LOCAL_DEPLOY_PATH}\id:C:\deploy
   environment:
    WORKER_EXECUTABLE_NAME_ENV: servicestart.ps1
       
   entrypoint: pwsh -Command "& C:\tools\entrypoints\worker\Development.ps1 @{ Path= \"C:\\deploy\"; Destination = \"C:\\Identity\"; }"
```

Note: I tried both \ and \ in file path but none of them working. Also powershell folder is also present within c:\Program Files

Any idea if I am missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The identity server does require a bit of customization to enable the deployments into the running container.

- Dockerfile customization

  There are 2 scripts that can be used for development purposes from the docker tools assets, one is used for web app hosted through IIS and other to be used for .NET Core apps like xConnect, identity server etc ([here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/developer-tools/deploying-files-into-running-containers.html)).

  The script used for .NET Core apps expects a executable to be available in `c:\service` folder of the container, which is run at the end of the entry point script.

  [image]

  To start up the `Identity server` after enabling the watch script we need to create a `PowerShell script (ServiceStart.ps1)` as per below and this will be used to configure using environment variable for the `Identity Server container`.

  ```
  dotnet.exe c:\identity\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll
  ```

  Create a Dockerfile for the identity server as per below. Make sure that `PowerShell script (ServiceStart.ps1)` is available in the context for the Dockerfile.

  ```
  # escape=`

  ARG BASE_IMAGE
  ARG TOOLING_IMAGE

  FROM ${TOOLING_IMAGE} as tooling

  FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

  SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';      $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

  # Copy development tools and entrypoint
  COPY --from=tooling \tools\ \tools\
  COPY .\servicestart.ps1 \service\
  ```
- Entry point configuration

  Once the Dockerfile is created for customizing the image when building the containers add the following configuration for identity server in `docker-compose.override.yaml` file.

```
id:      
  environment:
    Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__SitecoreMemberShipOptions__ConnectionString: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Core;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
    Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__AccountOptions__PasswordRecoveryUrl: https://${CM_HOST}/sitecore/login?rc=1
    Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__PasswordClient__ClientSecrets__ClientSecret1: ${SITECORE_IDSECRET}
    Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__DefaultClient__AllowedCorsOrigins__AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1: https://${CM_HOST}
    Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__CertificateRawData: ${SITECORE_ID_CERTIFICATE}
    Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__PublicOrigin: https://${ID_HOST}
    Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__CertificateRawDataPassword: ${SITECORE_ID_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD}
    Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
    WORKER_EXECUTABLE_NAME_ENV: servicestart.ps1    
  build:
    context: ./build/id
    args:
      BASE_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-id:${SITECORE_VERSION}
      TOOLING_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_TOOLS_REGISTRY}sitecore-docker-tools-assets:${TOOLS_VERSION}
  volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ./data/deploy/id
      target: c:\deploy        
  entrypoint: powershell -Command "& C:\tools\entrypoints\worker\Development.ps1 @{ Path = \"C:\\deploy\"; Destination = \"C:\\identity\"; }"
```

**WORKER_EXECUTABLE_NAME_ENV** environment variable which is used in the `Development.ps1`

**entrypoint** where we pass arguments to the Development.ps1 to map the path to watch for changes and path of the application to deploy.

**volumes** where we mount the host folder to `c:\deploy` folder inside the container.

Once the changes are deployed to identity server. It does need to be restarted for the changes to take effect `(use docker restart <container-name>)`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Sumit,Thanks for your answer but as you can see I have already used this variable.I used  the post https://praveenmanchanablog.wordpress.com/2021/01/02/deployment-into-sitecore-identity-server-container/   to implement this but somehow its not working for me. I assume it could be docker version issue.

Comment: Because in my identity container powershell file is present with name pwsh.exe